# Playwright cannot assess the returned defined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, playwright, queryselector

**Updated: `console.log(foodGroupIdsOnPage1)` works no matter outside or within the for-loop. So I think the problem is playwright(node package) cannot assess the "id" variable.**

I made a data scraper for one page of html which is successful to scrape the data. And the code is as below.

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

async function initialize() {                               //nodeJS

  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const context = await browser.newContext();

  const tab1 = await context.newPage();
  return { tab1, context };
}

async function main() {

  const { tab1, context } = await initialize();

  await tab1.goto('https://www.cfs.gov.hk/tc_chi/nutrient/search1.php');

  await tab1.waitForFunction(async function () {

    const foodGroupIdsOnPage1 = document.querySelector('.tableResponsive').querySelectorAll('td')

    const page1_foodGroupButton = foodGroupIdsOnPage1[0].querySelector('a')
    page1_foodGroupButton.click();

  });

  await tab1.waitForTimeout(2000);
  await tab1.click('[id^=grp] > a');

  await tab1.waitForTimeout(2000);
  const ArrayOfTabs = context.pages();


  let tab2 = ArrayOfTabs[1];
  await tab2.evaluate(function () {
    let tableOfAllFoods = []
    let rowsOnPage3 = document.querySelector(".colorTable2").querySelectorAll("tr");
    for (let row_OnPage3 of rowsOnPage3) {
      let arrayNutritionOfOneFood = []
      let cellsInOneRow = row_OnPage3.querySelectorAll("td");
      for (let cell of cellsInOneRow) {
        arrayNutritionOfOneFood.push(cell.innerText)
      }
      tableOfAllFoods.push(arrayNutritionOfOneFood);
    }
    console.log(tableOfAllFoods)
  });
  tab2.close();
  tab1.goBack();

}

main();
```

But then, i want to add a for-loop so that it can become a multi-page scraper. And the code breaks. The variable "id" on line 32 is undefined. And i don't know the reason why it is undefined.

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

async function initialize() {
    const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const context = await browser.newContext();                        ////create a new browser context, which means no cookies and cache saved
    const tab1 = await context.newPage();
    return { tab1, context };
}


async function main() {

    const { tab1, context } = await initialize();

    await tab1.goto('https://www.cfs.gov.hk/tc_chi/nutrient/search1.php');

    ////const page1_foodGroupsLinksArray = document.querySelector('.tableResponsive').querySelectorAll('td');


    // Node.js (Playwright) Context


    const foodGroupIdsOnPage1 = await tab1.evaluate(async function getFoodGroupsOnPage1() {

        return [...document.querySelector('.tableResponsive').querySelectorAll('td ')].map(e => e.id);
    })


    // Node.js context
    for (let id of foodGroupIdsOnPage1) {

        await tab1.waitForFunction(async function GotoPage2() {     ////wait for function>>>only run the next command after all the commands inside the next bracket run
            // Browser Context

            // for (let page1_foodGroupLink of page1_foodGroupsLinksArray) {

            const page1_foodGroupButton = document.querySelector(id).querySelector('a')         ////beginning of the for loop
            await page1_foodGroupButton.click();
        });

        ////console.log(id);
        await tab1.waitForTimeout(2000);
        await tab1.click('[id^=grp] > a');

        await tab1.waitForTimeout(2000);
        const ArrayOfTabs = context.pages();   ////get how many tabs chromium are

        let tab2 = ArrayOfTabs[1];              ////make active tab to the second tab
        await tab2.evaluate(function extractFoodGroupData() {
            let tableOfAllFoods = [];
            let rowsOnPage3 = document.querySelector(".colorTable2").querySelectorAll("tr");
            for (let row_OnPage3 of rowsOnPage3) {
                let arrayNutritionOfOneFood = [];
                let cellsInOneRow = row_OnPage3.querySelectorAll("td");
                for (let cell of cellsInOneRow) {
                    arrayNutritionOfOneFood.push(cell.innerText);
                }
                ////arrayNutritionOfOneFood.push(group_id);
                ////group_id=group_id+1;
                tableOfAllFoods.push(arrayNutritionOfOneFood);
            }
            console.log(tableOfAllFoods);
        });
        tab2.close();
        tab1.goBack();
        ////}
        ////},[id])

    }

};


main();
```

Would anyone please tell me how to fix and the reason why it breaks. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: It should be `document.querySelector('#' + id)` You need the `#` prefix to indicate that the selector is an ID.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. But terminal return this message: (node:18792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: page.waitForFunction: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: "   for (let id of foodGroupIdsOnPage1) {" this line

Comment: That makes no sense. That's the line that's defining the variable. The error can only happen when the variable is being referenced. That's really line 32?

Comment: ```console.log(foodGroupIdsOnPage1``` works no matter outside the loop or within the loop.

I think the problem is ```waitforfunction``` is a playwright function and it cannot assess ```id``` variable. Do you have any idea to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for the answer, please refer to https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page.
Try code below.

```
   await tab1.waitForFunction(async function GotoPage2(id) {     ////wait for function>>>only run the next command after all the commands inside the next bracket run
        // Browser Context

        // for (let page1_foodGroupLink of page1_foodGroupsLinksArray) {

        const page1_foodGroupButton = document.querySelector(id).querySelector('a')         ////beginning of the for loop
        await page1_foodGroupButton.click();
    }, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that `foodGroupIdsOnPage1` is `undefined`. Could you add a `console.log(foodGroupIdsOnPage1)` before the `for..of` loop and see if you're actually getting any results

Comment: The error message is about `id`, not `foodGroupIdsOnPage1`.

Comment: ```console.log(foodGroupIdsOnPage1``` works no matter outside the loop or within the loop.

I think the problem is ```waitforfunction``` is a playwright function and it cannot assess ```id``` variable. Do you have any idea to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated: `console.log(foodGroupIdsOnPage1)` works no matter outside or within the for-loop. So I think the problem is playwright(node package) cannot assess the `id` variable.**